# Override default GPG key in a git repo

Tags: git, gnupg

### Context

On my machine, I have set up a global git user in `~/.gitconfig`, with my private details:

```
[user]
    name = ebosi
    email = me@private-email.com
    signingkey = 0123456789ABCDEF
```

However, I want these global settings to be overridden by other credentials in some specific repos (the work ones, for example). In such case, I edit the local git config (say `~/work/project/.git/config`) as follows:

```
[user]
    name = ebosi
    email = ebosi@corporate.com
    signingkey = FEDCBA9876543210
```

### Problem

I want to GPG-sign my commits with the correct identity: default to the private one, except when overridden in the repo config.

However, when I `git commit -sS`, the sign-off identity is correctly picked up by git, but not the gpg key. For signing the commit using my corporate key, I need to `git commit -s -SFEDCBA9876543210`

### Question

How to make git automatically pick the correct gpg key?
(I.e. the signingkey defined in `./.git/config` if exists, else the one in `~/.gitconfig`)

Comment: This looks a lot like [this](https://filipekiss.com.br/multiple-gpg-keys-git/)!

Answer (score 4):

*Disclaimer: this answer is extensively based on Kiss' tutorial available [here](https://filipekiss.com.br/multiple-gpg-keys-git/) ([archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20200503161915/https://filipekiss.com.br/multiple-gpg-keys-git/)).*

---

Solving our issue is done via a *conditional import* of the work git config settings, based on the path of the project.

This is quite simple:

1. **Create** a new git config file, e.g. **`~/.gitconfig_work`**:

   ```
   touch ~/.gitconfig_work
   ```
2. Edit it to **define the “work” git config**:

   ```
   [user]
       name = ebosi
       email = ebosi@corporate.com
       signingkey = FEDCBA9876543210
   ```
3. **Load this file *conditionally* from `~/.gitconfig`**:

   ```
   [user]
       name = ebosi
       email = me@private-email.com
       signingkey = 0123456789ABCDEF

   …

   [includeIf "gitdir:~/work/"]
       path = ~/.gitconfig_work
   ```

This last step is the clever bit: it tells git to **load the “work config”** (and, thus, override the default settings) **only if it the repo is in the `~/work/` work directory** (or any subdirectory of it).

Note that:

- you specify the `gitdir` using the [same syntax as in `.gitignore` files](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-codegitdircode)
- `path = ~/.gitconfig_work` will simply expand to what is in the work config file, so you can also simply edit `.gitconfig` as follows:

  ```
  [user]
      name = ebosi
      email = me@private-email.com
      signingkey = 0123456789ABCDEF

  [includeIf "gitdir:~/work/"]
      [user]
          name = ebosi
          email = ebosi@corporate.com
          signingkey = FEDCBA9876543210
  ```
- `.gitconfig` is processed top-to-bottom, so if you want to override global parameters, make sure to import the new config *after* the default ones. What follows (where keys are sorted alphabetically) will *not* work:

  ```
  [includeIf "gitdir:~/work/"]
      path = ~/.gitconfig_work

  [user]
      name = ebosi
      email = me@private-email.com
      signingkey = 0123456789ABCDEF
  ```